# Discord-Bot only sends one command to the right channel, but all the Others to the wrong channel

Tags: python, ssh, discord

I'm currently working on a Discord-Bot for our shared flat. But since a couple of minutes ago, the Bot only recognizes "!help" as a valid command, and then sends it to the right channel, but as soon as the user types a different command, the bot sends it only to my "development"-channel. I've already changed the channel id, to the right channel but it doesn't change anything. Maybe something's flawed with the server I'm hosting on, but I'm not sure. I'd be happy if someone could help me.

```
async def on_message(c_message):
channel = client.get_channel(820750587624292366)
date = datetime.now()
date = str(date)
date = date.split(" ")
date = date[0]

if c_message.author.bot:
    return None
elif '!help' in c_message.content:
    return await c_message.channel.send("**!thisweek:** Der Putzdienst\n**!mynext:** Wann du das Nächste Mal dran bist.\r\n"
                                      "**!help:** Zeigt diese Hilfe an\n**!showlist:** Zeigt die aktuelle Einkaufsliste.\r\n"
                                      "**  -!add[Haushaltsmittel]:** Damit kannst du beliebige Dinge der Einkaufsliste hinzufügen [**BITTE NICHT MEHR ALS 1 ELEMENT pro Aufruf**].\r\n"
                                      "**  -!bought[Haushaltsmittel]:** Falls du etwas eingekauft hast, dass auf der Einkaufsliste stand.")
elif '!thisweek' in c_message.content:
    await c_message.channel.send(f'**_{date}:_**\n__**{", ".join(names[0])}**__:\nmüssen diese Woche **Gang und Küche** wischen,\r'
                                        '**Müll** runter bringen, **Flaschen** wegbringen und **Terrasse** ordentlich halten.\n\r'
                                        f'__**{", ".join(names[1])}**__:\nmüssen diese Woche die **Geschirrspülen ausräumen**,\r\n'
                                        '**Arbeitsplatten** sauber halten und **Ofen** und **Mikrowelle** putzen.')
```

PS: Sorry for the weak formatting on StackOverflow, my code in my IDE is formatted correctly.

Comment: I think you forgot to return it. If I understand your code right, it should send a message to the channel where it got the command from.
Otherwise it could be a missing bot permission, so just gain the bots role all necessary sending permissions.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. But after adding return, the problem still doesn't go away.

Comment: How/Where did you define `names`? For me everything works if I replace `names` with a normal text. Maybe this is the error.